# exit status 128 while cloning the git repository while getting go package from Github location

Tags: github, go, glide-golang

I want to configure the GoLang GB compiler for the projects in my local. based on the documentation given in the  [url](https://getgb.io/docs/install/) I am trying to get the gb compiler using the command 
[image]

its returning status code 128. I am unable to understand whats happening here as there is no reference to resolve this issue.

adding GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 or 2 is not helping as its not giving any other valuable details as output.

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 go get -u -v github.com/constabulary/gb/...
$ github.com/constabulary/gb (download)
$ # cd .; git clone https://github.com/constabulary/gb 
  C:\work\GitHub\GoLib\src\github.com\constabulary\gb
  Cloning into 'C:\work\GitHub\GoLib\src\github.com\constabulary\gb'...
  package github.com/constabulary/gb/...: exit status 128
```

Still getting the avove output

below is the output when not using -u

```
$ GIT_TRACE=2 go get -v github.com/constabulary/gb/...
github.com/constabulary/gb (download)
# cd .; git clone https://github.com/constabulary/gb 
C:\work\GitHub\GoLib\src\github.com\constabulary\gb
17:20:25.818538 git.c:328               trace: built-in: git 'clone' 
'https://github.com/constabulary/gb' 'C:\work\GitHub\GoLib\                                                
src\github.com\constabulary\gb'
17:20:25.867542 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: 'remote-https' 
'origin' 'https://github.com/constabulary/gb'
Cloning into 'C:\work\GitHub\GoLib\src\github.com\constabulary\gb'...
17:20:25.970553 git.c:560               trace: exec: 'git-remote-https' 
'origin' 'https://github.com/constabulary/gb'
17:20:25.970553 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: 'git-remote-
https' 'origin' 'https://github.com/constabulary/gb'
package github.com/constabulary/gb/...: exit status 128
```

Comment: Run the same command while having `GIT_TRACE=1` and `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` in your environment.

Comment: Another minor point: text consoles in Windows do support copying text from them; please copy and paste this text and format it as code; do not post screenshots: they are not indexed by google.

Comment: It could be a network issue, please make sure your connection is ok and try to add "-v" flag to enable debug output.

Comment: @Radi : I dont see any network Issues Here.

Comment: Did you tried the same command without update flag "-u"?

Comment: That is odd, I just tried now (MacOS) and worked fine. Are you using Git for Windows or MinGW/CygWin?

Comment: same process to clone any repository was working couple of days back. but its not working now..

Comment: This is a genuine Issue that Im facing. Im not sure Why people are voting it with Downvote

Comment: Have you changed anything in your global git config? Have you updated your git installation? Have you tried removing the repos and starting from scratch? Can you do the git clones manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to resolve the issue for a couple of days.
In My configuration I was on organizational GitHub and the codelibrary I was trying to get was from github.com. So I thought that might be causing the issue. But that was not true.

I suspected that there is something wrong with the git configuration. as even Organizational github account was not accessible. I tried a lot of solutions from multiple threads.. nothing worked.

Then I ultimately uninstalled GitHub and tortoise git from My machine and installed it again.
and did the complete git configuration setup on my machine from scratch.

It Worked.

What caused that issue in the first place was identified when I went to uninstall git. Installation date was the date when the issue started. So i suspect that there was some faulty update installed for git unknowingly and that caused this issue.